# How to compile dependent .java files located in different packages

Tags: java, import, package

I have a folder named pack, inside that there are two folders p1 and p2.

inside folder p1 i write the following code in file named sum.java

```
package pack.p1;
public class sum{
public static void Display_Sum(int a,int b){
System.out.println("Sum = "+(a+b));
}
}
```

then inside folder p2 i write following code in file named wap8.java

```
package pack.p2;
import pack.p1.sum;
import java.util.Scanner;
class wap8{
public static void main(String args[]){
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter two no.s = ");
int a=s.nextInt();
int b=s.nextInt();
sum.Display_Sum(a,b);

}
}
```

Here is my flow of execution in cmd prompt.
First i create the class file of sum.java by executing

**H:\Java\WAP 4\pack\p1>javac sum.java**

then i set the classpath for sum as

**H:\Java\WAP 4\pack\p1>set classpath=%classpath%;h:\Java\WAP 4\pack;**

then in cmd line i come to folder p2 and execute the following, but it shows package pack.p1 doesnt exist. Why is this so??

H:\Java\WAP 4\pack\p2>javac wap8.java

wap8.java:2: error: package pack.p1 does not exist

import pack.p1.sum;

```
          ^
```

wap8.java:10: error: cannot find symbol

sum.Display_Sum(a,b);

^

symbol:   variable sum

location: class wap8

2 errors

I even tried setting classpath vairable in environment variables with ***variable name*** as **CLASSPATH** and ***variable value*** as **H:\Java\WAP 4\pack;**. STILL NOT WORKING when i execute javac wap8.java and showing the same error as above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overly complicating things for no good reason. Use the following steps and you should be good.

1. Navigate to the `H:\Java\WAP 4\pack\p1` directory.
2. `javac sum.java`
3. Navigate to `H:\Java\WAP 4\` directory.
4. `javac pack\p2\wap8.java`

That's it. No need to be setting `CLASSPATH` explicitly. The reason why you have to compile `wap8` from the `WAP 4` folder is because the package statement in a class binds it to the fully qualified name. So `sum1` has the FQN as  `pack.p1.sum` and `wap8` has the FQN as `pack.p2.wap8`. Therefore, `javac` won't be able to see `pack.p1.sum` when you are in the `pack\p2` folder.

You can run your code from `H:\Java\WAP 4` directory using `java pack.p2.wap8`

Comment: Well thats fine. but i read the same can be solved by setting the classpath for the  class file sum and then executing "javac wap8.java" from p2 fodler and running class file from the same p2 folder using "java wap8". Please help me with setting the classpath for the above program and its execution

Comment: please help me setting the classpath and solving the above task